# ios 6.1.4 uiactivitycontroller crashed in UIRemoteViewControllerConnectionRequest _sendServiceViewControllerRequest] + 202

Tags: uiactivityviewcontroller

The crash happens in UIActivityController, when email option is clicked. This happens only first time launch. I stack trace i didnt not find anything related to my application. Entire trace is shown in ios framework. Any one experienced such problem? Please help.

Here is the code

```
if(NSClassFromString(@"UIActivityViewController")) {
        // iOS 6
        NSMutableArray *activityItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSMutableArray *applicationActivities = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        if ([UIPrintInteractionController isPrintingAvailable])
        {
            UIViewPrintFormatter *formatter = [self.descriptionWebview viewPrintFormatter];
            [activityItems addObject:formatter];
        }

        if (pdfLink)
        {
            [activityItems addObject:pdfLink];
            PDFActivity *pdfActivity = [[PDFActivity alloc] init];
            [applicationActivities addObject:pdfActivity];
        }

        MailActivityItemSource *mailItemSource = [[MailActivityItemSource alloc] initWithInsightsObject:insightsObj];
        [activityItems addObject:mailItemSource];

        UIActivityViewController* shareMenu = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:applicationActivities];
        [shareMenu setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
            [self dismissActivityController];
            [self LoadPage];
        }];

        shareMenu.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToFacebook, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo];
//        [self presentModalViewController:shareMenu animated:YES];
        [self presentViewController:shareMenu animated:YES completion:Nil];
    }
    else {
```

Here is the log :

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  5

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x344383e2 __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3c13395e objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x34437ebc __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 124
3   UIKit                           0x365d1210 __54+[_UIAppearance _recordersExcludingSource:withWindow:]_block_invoke_0 + 328
4   CoreFoundation                  0x34435752 __NSDictionaryEnumerate + 698
5   UIKit                           0x365d10b8 +[_UIAppearance _recordersExcludingSource:withWindow:] + 132
6   UIKit                           0x366af408 UIViewServiceCurrentAppearanceSerializedRepresentations + 56
7   UIKit                           0x3663d946 -[_UIRemoteViewControllerConnectionRequest _sendServiceViewControllerRequest] + 202
8   UIKit                           0x3663d7da __block_global_5 + 258
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x3c55080a _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 22
10  UIKit                           0x3663d6ce __76-[_UIRemoteViewControllerConnectionRequest _connectToViewControllerOperator]_block_invoke_0 + 90
11  UIKit                           0x36646d24 __block_global_0 + 28
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x3c54e586 dispatch_once_f + 42
13  UIKit                           0x36646cfe __73-[_UIViewServiceSessionEndpoint connectToDeputyOfType:connectionHandler:]_block_invoke_0 + 86
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x3c54d78e _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 6
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x3c550b36 _dispatch_queue_drain + 138
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x3c54e678 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 40
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x3c55160e _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 206
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x3c5517d4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 88
19  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c5757ec _pthread_wqthread + 356
20  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c575680 start_wqthread + 4


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c616e30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c616fd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3440d2b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3440bfd6 __CFRunLoopRun + 814
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3437f238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3437f0c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   GraphicsServices                0x37f5e336 GSEventRunModal + 70
7   UIKit                           0x3629b2b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
8   Northern Trust                  0x000c1672 main (main.m:43)
9   Northern Trust                  0x000c13ec start + 36

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c6175d0 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3c552d22 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 806
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3c54e374 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 32

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c616e30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c616fd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3440d2b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3440c02c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3437f238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3437f0c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x3a387390 RunWebThread(void*) + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c5800de _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c57ffa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c616e30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c616fd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3440d2b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3440c02c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3437f238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3437f0c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   Foundation                      0x34ccc888 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 304
7   Foundation                      0x34d5022c __NSThread__main__ + 968
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c5800de _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c57ffa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c627d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c575ad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c5757f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c575680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.uikit._UIRemoteViewControllerCreationRequest com.apple.MailCompositionService ComposeServiceRemoteViewController 0x3cb4d2cc
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c627350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c59dfb2 pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c5da366 abort + 90
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3bb82dda abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3bb80094 default_terminate() + 20
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3c133a58 _objc_terminate() + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3bb80118 safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3bb801b0 std::terminate() + 16
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3bb8159a __cxa_throw + 118
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3c13399e objc_exception_throw + 90
10  CoreFoundation                  0x34437ebc __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 124
11  UIKit                           0x365d1210 __54+[_UIAppearance _recordersExcludingSource:withWindow:]_block_invoke_0 + 328
12  CoreFoundation                  0x34435754 __NSDictionaryEnumerate + 700
13  UIKit                           0x365d10b8 +[_UIAppearance _recordersExcludingSource:withWindow:] + 132
14  UIKit                           0x366af408 UIViewServiceCurrentAppearanceSerializedRepresentations + 56
15  UIKit                           0x3663d946 -[_UIRemoteViewControllerConnectionRequest _sendServiceViewControllerRequest] + 202
16  UIKit                           0x3663d7da __block_global_5 + 258
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x3c55080a _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 22
18  UIKit                           0x3663d6ce __76-[_UIRemoteViewControllerConnectionRequest _connectToViewControllerOperator]_block_invoke_0 + 90
19  UIKit                           0x36646d26 __block_global_0 + 30
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x3c54e586 dispatch_once_f + 42
21  UIKit                           0x36646cfe __73-[_UIViewServiceSessionEndpoint connectToDeputyOfType:connectionHandler:]_block_invoke_0 + 86
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x3c54d790 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x3c550b36 _dispatch_queue_drain + 138
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x3c54e678 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 40
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x3c551610 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 208
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x3c5517d4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 88
27  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c5757ee _pthread_wqthread + 358
28  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c575680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c627594 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x34411474 __CFSocketManager + 676
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c5800de _pthread_start + 306
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c57ffa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 7 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c62708c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c578afc _pthread_cond_wait + 644
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c578870 pthread_cond_timedwait + 40
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x38354df6 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 102
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x38467532 JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 78
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x3847a030 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c5800de _pthread_start + 306
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c57ffa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 8 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c62708c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c578afc _pthread_cond_wait + 644
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c582cf8 pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x383fa6dc JSC::SlotVisitor::drainFromShared(JSC::SlotVisitor::SharedDrainMode) + 140
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x383fa620 JSC::MarkStackThreadSharedData::markingThreadMain() + 140
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x3847a030 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c5800de _pthread_start + 306
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c57ffa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 9 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c616e30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c616fd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3440d2b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3440c02c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3437f238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3437f0c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x3a421ccc WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 140
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x3847a030 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c5800de _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c57ffa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c627d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c575ad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c5757f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c575680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c627d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c575ad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c5757f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c575680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c627d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c575ad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c5757f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c575680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c627d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c575ad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c5757f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c575680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c627d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c575ad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c5757f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c575680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x3e0e9524
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x0491b000      r6: 0x21c14ee4      r7: 0x0491a924
    r8: 0x21c14ec0    r9: 0x00000888     r10: 0x3c7a2080     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x0491a918      lr: 0x3c59dfb7      pc: 0x3c627350
  cpsr: 0x00000010
```